# get route by name not id - laravel 10

Tags: laravel

route by {id} for example /author/{id} isn't problem form me but i want to have route by {name} for example /author/{name}

i have code idea but i get 404 not found error:

php 8.2
laravel 10
code:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/authors/{authorname}', [AuthorController::class, 'showByName'])->name('authors.showbyname');
```

**Controller**

```
public function showbyname(author $authorsname)
{
    $authors = author::with(['book.personaldata'])->get();

    return view('authors.show',  compact('authorname', 'authors' ));

}
```

```
<a href="{{ url('/author/' . urlencode($author->name)) }}">
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

(working code but show by {id})

```
 <a href="{{ route('authors.show', ['author' => $author->id])  }}"/a>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function show(author $author)
    {
       $authors = author::with(['personaldata.book'])->get();
        return view('author.show', compact('author', 'authors' ,));

    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/authors/{author}', [authorController::class,'show'])->name('authors.show');
```

Comment: Your route is `/authors/...` but you link to `/author/...`. Why not use the route name to link to? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: For the route `/authors/{id}`, `author $id` would use the number (like `/authors/1`) to pull an `author` instance from the database using that `id`. For the route `/authors/{authorname}`, you'll need to [Customize the Key](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key). Also, `compact('$authorname', 'authors')` is a mistake; `'$authorname'` should simply be `'authorname'`.

Comment: @brombeer after double checking syntax everything same error

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::get('/authors/{name}', [NameController::class, 'nameDetail']);
```

Controller

```
use App\Models\Name;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function nameDetail($name)
{
    $detail = Name::where('name', $name)->get();

    return response(['success' => $detail], 200);

}
```

Comment: name is a parameter taken from the authors' database

Answer (score 0):

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/authors/{authorname}', [AuthorController::class, 'showByName'])->name('authors.showbyname');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function showByName($authorname)
{
    $author = Author::with(['book.personaldata'])->where('name', $authorname)->firstOrFail();
    return view('authors.show', compact('author'));
}
```

**Link**

```html
<a href="{{ route('authors.showbyname',$author->name) }}">
```

Comment: Still 404 error, maybe i have error in some other place. Any sugesstions? i have added to post code that is working coreclty but show by id